# EVO PDF: Side-by-side tables & repeating headers

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, evopdf

I'm using the EVO PDF, Html-> PDF generator, and I've come across a scenario that I cannot seem to solve. I'm unsure if a solution exists with the software itself.

I have 2 metric data tables that are side by side, using data that always creates the same amount of rows. The reason they are not a single table is, 1) data is showing different scopes, and 2) styling purposes.

EVO PDF will repeat all table headers for tables that get cutoff at page-break, and display them at the top of the next page. The issue is if 2 tables get cutoff, the software creates "two" headers at the top of the next page. Each of the headers spans the entire page width, and they stack on top of one another. Visually the table headers are the correct width, but the second header is "bumped" down.

Is anyone aware of a way to have the headers coexist, per se? Or has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now the default behavior in the latest version of EVO and the headers and footers are displayed side by side. You can still switch to the old rendering mode if you set HtmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.StackRepeatedTableHeaders = true.

Answer (score 1):

We just experienced the same problem. We contacted support@evopdf.com and they directed us to the latest build which fixes it. You should contact them.